# select single link on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the hyperlinks on my website have a certain css animation effect.

My code:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function() {
  this.addClass("myeffect");
}
```

It works fine so far, but when I hover a link, every link on the website start showing the effect, not only the one I've mouse-hovered.
How can I have only the link which is being hovered show the effect?

Comment: Can you modify the CSS?

Comment: Are you sure this code matches what you are doing?  Because this code has a logical error.  `this` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Of course it does.  The CSS selector `"a"` quite literally matches every link.

Comment: jQuery does not bind the `this` as a jQuery object inside it's event handlers by default.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xfxw260L/  `this` is the dom element, it's not wrapped in a jQuery object.  `addClass` is a jQuery method.  You have to wrap the this in a jQuery object if you want to use the class.

Comment: Why don't you use a:hover{} as a style sheet effect rather than using or doing it in a jQuery?

Comment: @Taplar not sure the OP has the actual code he's using in the question.  The DOM element has no `.addClass` function, this should just fail ... but he claims it's "working fine"

Comment: That's why my first question was for the actual code @Tibrogargan

Comment: I tryed it like this before: `$("a").mouseenter(function() {$("a").addClass("myeffect");}` It didn't work either ...

Comment: Because the inner $('a') is going to find all of them, which reflects the issue you are talking about.  Don't do the inner lookup.  Use $(this) like the answer says below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `this` return you the current element/node. And there is no `addClass` method available to it.

You need to select that element from the node and add `class` to it.

`$(this)` will select that particular element

```js
$("a").mouseenter(function() {
   
  $(this).addClass("myeffect");
})
```

```css
.myeffect{
color : red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#">5</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing `this` incorrectly.

```
$("a").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass("myeffect");
}
```

Comment: this made it a lot better! the code is not fully working yet, because it is more complex I guess, but this helped a lot. thanks!

Comment: just another update: this totaly made it work for me now. There were some other issues I had to fix, but this is the right answer for my question. thanks a lot!